# Preferred development platform Classic or Lightning?

Tags: lightning-apps, appexchange

What should be the preferred app development platform Classic or Lightning? If i develop an app on lightning platform will it be backward compatible in classic mode?

Thanks

Comment: It depends on the requirement. You may need to [compare the features](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lex_aloha_comparison.htm&type=5) between those two.

Answer (score 3):

The parts of your app that make use of the default layout-based user-interface will work in both modes.

But for custom code:

- Classic: Visualforce is written
- Lightning: Lightning Components are written

Now Visualforce can be made to work in Lightning - [Lightning Ready](https://partners.salesforce.com/s/education/general/Lightning_Ready) - and Lightning Components can be made to work in Classic - [Lightning Out](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_out.htm). But this takes extra work and brings limitations.

Best to do plenty of research now before making a decision e.g. [Make the Move to Lightning Experience](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/trails/lex_admin_migration).

Also you need to consider your customer base. If they are 100% Classic or 100% Lightning the decision is easy. But if it's a mix, decisions are harder in that you may feel it necessary to cover both rather than go for only Lightning. (Lightning will eventually become the standard.)

Answer (score 2):

Lightning is the way forward. You can see release notes, 95% of the features are on lightning. Salesforce is pushing lightning with full potential. If you have the legacy project with VF then slowly migrate if its new project it doesn't make sense to start with a classic.

In the end, it boils down to what you have and how much future proof you want your project to be.